# Transformers and BERT: dealing with possessives and apostrophes when encode

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

Let's consider two sentences:

```
"why isn't Alex's text tokenizing? The house on the left is the Smiths' house"
```

Now let's tokenize and decode:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_lower_case=True)
tokenizer.decode(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenizer.tokenize("why isn't Alex's text tokenizing? The house on the left is the Smiths' house")))
```

We get:

```
"why isn't alex's text tokenizing? the house on the left is the smiths'house"
```

**My question is how dealing with missing space in some possessives like *smiths'house*?**

For me, it seems that the process of tokenization in Transformers is done not right. Let's consider output of

```
tokenizer.tokenize("why isn't Alex's text tokenizing? The house on the left is the Smiths' house")
```

we get:

```
['why', 'isn', "'", 't', 'alex', "'", 's', 'text', 'token', '##izing', '?', 'the', 'house', 'on', 'the', 'left', 'is', 'the', 'smith', '##s', "'", 'house']
```

So in this step, we already have lost important information about the last apostrophe. It would be much better if tokenization was done in the another way:

```
['why', 'isn', "##'", '##t', 'alex', "##'", '##s', 'text', 'token', '##izing', '?', 'the', 'house', 'on', 'the', 'left', 'is', 'the', 'smith', '##s', "##'", 'house']
```

In this way, tokenization keeps all information about apostrophes, and we will not have problems with possessives.

Comment: Why do you have the exact same example text sentence as this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852030/how-to-detokenize-a-berttokenizer-output Are you the same user?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 No. Just saw that question before and got my own question.